# The post method not posting all data from the html form

Tags: php

I have the following element in my html form

```
<input type="text" name="date[]" value="25-05-2015"/>
```

the above element appears 169 times in the form

When I submit the form only date[] posted upto 124 values

Is there any problem with th post limit...?

Comment: You have the `<form action="youraction" method='yourway'> <input type="text" name="date[]" value="25-05-2015"/> </form>` in your php file ??

Comment: check `post_max_size` in your php.ini file

Comment: Maybe `max_input_vars`? http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars Anything in the error_logs and/or error logging on?

Comment: This is my form 
<form name="form_name" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="date[]" value="25-05-2015"/>
.
.
.
169 times
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
in php 
print_r($_POST['date']); upto 124 time

post_max_size = 80M in php.ini

Comment: Do share the your form complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I see thats date array element. using :

```
<form name="form_name" method="post" action=""> <input type="text" name="date[0]" value="25-05-2015"/> . . . 169 times <input type="submit" name="submit"/> </form>
```

or

```
<form name="form_name" method="post" action=""> <input type="text" name="date" value="25-05-2015"/> . . . 169 times <input type="submit" name="submit"/> </form>
```