# post method array in 80 of 49 only taking other then missed why?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

when i append row with the attribute array called name="name[]" after post method in 80 of 49 only taking other then missed why ? **when submitting the form** . 
every row append by user

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="select[]"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="input[]"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="select[]"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="input[]"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="select[]"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="input[]"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="select[]"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="input[]"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="select[]"></select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="input[]"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

like this but when submit the form not getting all values .

Comment: `after post method in 80 of 49 only taking other then missed why` - OK, you need to find a better translator

Comment: Why do you have empty `<select>` tags?

Comment: CHeck comments from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497603/the-post-method-not-posting-all-data-from-the-html-form

Comment: You need to do setting in PHP.INI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `max_input_vars` [php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars](http://#) Anything in the error_logs and/or error logging on?